# How to do this in all subdirectories in parent folder using batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script

i am total noob for scripting so i need small help with this batch script... Here is script :

```
@ECHO OFF

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET par2_path="C:\PAR2\phpar2.exe"
SET par2_redundancy=10

:PARING

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cd') do (
     set foldername=%%~nxA
    )

echo. Current Folder Name: %foldername%

%par2_path% c -s1920000 -r%par2_redundancy% -l "%foldername%.par2" "*.r*" & goto eof
```

I need to perform this in all subdirectories in parent folder... Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet could help (note that `ECHO` prefix is there for debugging purposes only in the `ECHO %par2_path% ...` line).

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /S /A:D') do (

  pushd %%~fA

  echo. Current Folder Name: %%~nxA
  rem set foldername=%%~nxA
  ECHO %par2_path% c -s1920000 -r%par2_redundancy% -l "%%~nxA.par2" "*.r*"

  popd
)
```

Read more about [Pushd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771180.aspx) and [Popd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771942.aspx) commands.